# How not to allow variable input not of type STRING

Tags: java, arrays

I have two questions, first of all I have software that takes names and I want to not allow the reception of a variable that is not String How do I do it? And second thing I did a code section whose goal is to sort songs according to their singer (he gets an array of songs containing the name of the singer and I want him to make a list of songs that each singer has) but something that does not work.
Thank you:)
this is the code:

```
public void miunBySinger(Song[] song3){
    int place =0;
    int numChecking = 0;

    System.out.println("this is your songs list sorts by name of singer");
    for (int i = 0; i < song3.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("song of"+song3[i].getSinger()+ ":");
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < song3.length; i1++) {
            if (song3[place].getSinger().equals( song3[place+numChecking].getSinger())){
                System.out.println(song3[place+numChecking].getName());
            }
            if (numChecking + place < song3.length) {
                numChecking++;
            }else {
                numChecking =1;
                place++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My first time on the site - This is a mistake

Comment: @vandench Huh?  It's clearly Java, unless JavaScript implemented `System.out.println` when I wasn't looking.

Comment: This originally had jQuery and HTML code.

Comment: It actually appears to have had the instructions for putting code in the window, but whatever :)

Comment: do you mean menuBySinger?

Comment: Please edit your question and ask only 1 question if other is not in same line

Answer (score 0):

You have the code:

```
if (numChecking + place < song3.length) {
    numChecking++;
```

The problem is that if `numChecking + place` is exactly 1 less than `song3.length`, then when you increment `numChecking`, `numChecking + place` will then be *equal* to `song3.length`.  So when you try to access the array at that index, it will be off the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> "first of all I have software that takes names and I want to not allow
>   the reception of a variable that is not String. How do I do it?"

To you.... what would **not** be considered a String? If you set your input mechanism to only accept a String then golly gee, that's what you'll get. In reality it's all a matter of what characters you would allow to be within a String so you can use the [**String.matches()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method to carry out a mild form of validation on the String contents which is input from User (or whatever the input source might be).

Let's pretend that we have a String variable named **artist** and we are going to accept User input to fill that variable with a valid name from the Console window. If the name String isn't found to be valid (according to our rules) then we inform the User and let him/her try again.

To begin with **you** need to decide what the 'name validity rules' are and for the sake of this simple example we are just going to have these:

1. Allow any alpha letters from a to z or A to Z;
2. Allow commas (,);
3. Allow periods (.);
4. Allow hyphens (-);
5. Allow apostrophes (');
6. Allow white-spaces;
7. Don't allow any other keyboard character other than rules 1 to 6.

The above rules can be easily applied to the [**String.Matches()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method using a [**Regular Expression**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) since the method accepts them. To institute the above rules we will use the following RegEx:

**"[a-zA-Z.,'\\- ]+"**

and here is an explanation of what the RegEx does:

[image]

To implement what is mentioned above you might have code that looks like this:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

String artist = "";
while (artist.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a Singer Name (or quit): -> ");
    artist = userInput.nextLine();
    if (artist.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        System.err.println("Bye-Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // Regular Expression used to validate input. 
    // Notice the NOT operator (!).
    if (!artist.matches("[a-zA-Z.,'\\- ]+")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Name! Try again...\n");
        artist = "";
    }
} 

// Any Continuing Method Code Here:
System.out.println("Processing songs for the singer: " + artist 
                 + "\nPlease wait...\n");
```

Again, you need to be the one that determines the rules for what would be considered "a valid String". This isn't too difficult for names of people. Letter case is not really an issue either in this particular situation since the String class does have the [**String.equalsIgnoreCase()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm) method as well. Just add the characters you want allowed for validation within the Regular expression but do keep in mind that some characters (like the hyphen) are considered special RegEx characters and need to be Escaped with the Escape character (\).

> "second thing I did a code section whose goal is to sort songs
>   according to their singer (he gets an array of songs containing the
>   name of the singer and I want him to make a list of songs that each
>   singer has) but something that does not work."

I had to read this a few times to get a grasp of what I think you're really asking here and to be honest, I'm still not sure. Are you talking about **sorting** or do you actually mean ***"display song titles according to their respective Artists in a list type fashion"***? Perhaps it's both.

In any case sorting is the way to go and there are a lot ways to do it in Java. At this time it's also important to note that it would of been helpful if you had also provided the code for the **Song** Class so for the sake of the examples shown below I created a **Songs** Class:

**The Songs Class:**

```
public class Songs {

    private String songTitle;
    private String artistName;

    public Songs(String songName, String singerName) {
        this.songTitle = songName;
        this.artistName = singerName;
    }

    public Songs() {
        songTitle = null;
        artistName = null;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return songTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String songName) {
        this.songTitle = songName;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtist(String singerName) {
        this.artistName = singerName;
    }

    public void sort(Songs[] songs) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Place the songs array into a List collection as a single
        // string placing the Artist first and using the Pipe (|)
        // character as a delimiter between Artist and Title. This
        // ensures that the sorting will be done based on the Artist's 
        // name will be sorted and because Titles with the same artist
        // the titles appear to be sorted as well. This can also be 
        // done with a Comparator but this allows you to clearly see
        // what's going on and allows you to make the sort the way you
        // want.
        for (Songs song : songs) {
            list.add(song.getArtist() + "|" + song.getTitle());
        }

        // Sort the collection (ascending order)
        Collections.sort(list);

        // Convert the List back into our original songs Array
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String[] tmp = list.get(i).split("\\|");
            songs[i] = new Songs(tmp[1], tmp[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return songTitle + " By " + artistName;
    }
}
```

You will notice that in this Songs class there are what you would expect to be typical *Fields* along with *Getter* and *Setter* methods but there is also a custom **toString()** method and a **sort()** method which only excepts a single dimensional Songs[] Array as an argument. This way you can keep the sorting business in one house so to speak.

Let's create a Songs Array:

```
Songs[] songs = new Songs[10];
songs[0] = new Songs("Up On The Roof", "The Drifters");
songs[1] = new Songs("On Broadway", "The Drifters");
songs[2] = new Songs("It's All Over Now", "The Rolling Stones");
songs[3] = new Songs("Time Is On My Side", "The Rolling Stones");
songs[4] = new Songs("Dance, Dance, Dance", "The Beach Boys");
songs[5] = new Songs("Do You Wanna Dance", "The Beach Boys");
songs[6] = new Songs("I Don't Believe In You", "Talk Talk");
songs[7] = new Songs("I Believe In You", "Talk Talk");
songs[8] = new Songs("Hold On", "Wilson Phillips");
songs[9] = new Songs("Release Me", "Wilson Phillips");
```

This array contains 10 song Titles and the 5 Artists that sang them. As you can see there is no real sorting to the elements of the array but we'll take care of that now with our **Songs.sort()** method and then we'll list the Artists to the Console Window with their related Song Titles beneath them:

```
// Sort the songs Array..,
new Songs().sort(songs);

// Display the Array by artist and their related titles.
String currentArtist = "";
// Iterate through the songs Array
for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    String artistName = songs[i].getArtist(); // artist from current song index
    String songTitle = songs[i].getTitle();   // Titlet from current song index
    // Make sure we only display the Artist once.
    if (!currentArtist.equals(artistName)) {
        System.out.println("\nSongs By: " + songs[i].getArtist());
    }
    // Display the Title(s) relate to the current Artist
    System.out.println("\t  " + songs[i].getTitle());
    currentArtist = artistName; // Update who is the current Artist
}
```

When the above code is run the Console Window will display:

```
Songs By: Talk Talk
      I Believe In You
      I Don't Believe In You

Songs By: The Beach Boys
      Dance, Dance, Dance
      Do You Wanna Dance

Songs By: The Drifters
      On Broadway
      Up On The Roof

Songs By: The Rolling Stones
      It's All Over Now
      Time Is On My Side

Songs By: Wilson Phillips
      Hold On
      Release Me
```

Notice how the Artists are listed in alphabetical order as are the song Titles beneath them.

> **Tying it all together...**

Now it's time to put it all together whereas we're going to create a console display application where the User is asked to enter the name of a particular Artist and the app will seek through the songs Array and create yet another array named **artistSongs** based on that artist name supplied if it exists. If the artist name doesn't exist then the User is notified and given the opportunity to enter another Artist name (or quit the application by entering **quit**).

To completely pull this off we'll need yet another method named **getSongsByArtist()** which will take our **songs** array and the User supplied artist name as arguments so as to build our **artistSongs** Array. Here is the whole runnable code (you will need the **Songs** class posted above):

**The Console Application (requires Songs Class above):**

```
package songsexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SongsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SongsExample().startApp();
    }

    private void startApp() {
        // Declare and initialize the songs array for 10 songs. 
        Songs[] songs = new Songs[10];
        // Fill the Array...
        songs[0] = new Songs("Up On The Roof", "The Drifters");
        songs[1] = new Songs("On Broadway", "The Drifters");
        songs[2] = new Songs("It's All Over Now", "The Rolling Stones");
        songs[3] = new Songs("Time Is On My Side", "The Rolling Stones");
        songs[4] = new Songs("Dance, Dance, Dance", "The Beach Boys");
        songs[5] = new Songs("Do You Wanna Dance", "The Beach Boys");
        songs[6] = new Songs("I Don't Believe In You", "Talk Talk");
        songs[7] = new Songs("I Believe In You", "Talk Talk");
        songs[8] = new Songs("Hold On", "Wilson Phillips");
        songs[9] = new Songs("Release Me", "Wilson Phillips");

        // displayAllSongs(songs);

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String artist = "";
        while (artist.equals("")) {
            // Prompt for Artist name from User
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a Artist Name (or quit): -> ");
            artist = userInput.nextLine();
            if (artist.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Bye-Bye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            // Is the supplied name from User valid (meets our rules)?  
            if (!artist.matches("[a-zA-Z.,'\\- ]+")) {
                // No it's not. Inform & allow User to try again
                System.err.println("Invalid Artist Name! Try again...\n");
                artist = "";
                continue; // Go to top of loop.
            }

            // Name is valid...
            System.out.println("Processing songs for the Artist: " + artist
                    + "\nPlease wait...");

            // Get song titles by the Artist supplied from User 
            Songs[] artistSongs = getSongsByArtist(songs, artist);

            // Are there songs by Artist?
            if (artistSongs.length > 0) {
                // Yes there is...
                new Songs().sort(artistSongs); // Sort the artistSongs Array.

                //sortSongs(artistSongs); // Sort the artistSongs Array.
                // Display the Artist's name.
                System.out.println("\nSongs By: " + artistSongs[0].getArtist());
                //Display the Artist's song titles...
                for (int i = 0; i < artistSongs.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("\t  " + artistSongs[i].getTitle());
                }
            }
            else {
                // No such artist found.
                System.out.println("There are no found Titles by: " + artist);
            }
            artist = "";
        }
    }

    private void displayAllSongs(Songs[] songs) {
        // Sort the songs Array..,
        new Songs().sort(songs);

        // Display the Array by artist and their related titles.
        String currentArtist = "";
        // Iterate through the songs Array
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
            String artistName = songs[i].getArtist(); // artist from current song index
            String songTitle = songs[i].getTitle();   // Titlet from current song index
            // Make sure we only display the Artist once.
            if (!currentArtist.equals(artistName)) {
                System.out.println("\nSongs By: " + songs[i].getArtist());
            }
            // Display the Title(s) relate to the current Artist
            System.out.println("\t  " + songs[i].getTitle());
            currentArtist = artistName; // Update who is the current Artist
        }
    }

    public Songs[] getSongsByArtist(Songs[] songs, String artistName) {
        List<Songs> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Songs song : songs) {
            // See if the artist name in Array contains the 
            // supplied artist name. Everything is brought to
            // lowercase so that there is no case sensitivity 
            // and the String.contains() method is used to reduce
            // some need for name accuracy.
            if (song.getArtist().toLowerCase().contains(artistName.toLowerCase())) {
                list.add(song);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new Songs[0]);
    }
}
```